# How to fit model with semivariogram using gstat in R?

Tags: r, spatial, kriging, gstat, covariogram

I have a csv file file contains atmospheric PM10 concentration data of 1 march,12.00 pm.[please, download.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByY3OAw62EShQ2owdk5FVUhOUDA/view?usp=sharing) I want to draw a semivariogram using gstat package in R. I tried to write these code in R. but with these data, I cant fit the model.

```
    library(sp)
    library(gstat)

    seoul3112<-read.csv("seoul3112.csv")
    seoul3112<-na.omit(seoul3112)

    g<-gstat(id="PM10",formula=PM10~LON+LAT,location=~LON+LAT,
             data=seoul3112)
    seoul3112.var<-variogram(g,width=0.04,cutoff=0.6)
    seoul3112.var
    plot(seoul3112.var, col="black", pch=16,cex=1.3,
         xlab="Distance",ylab="Semivariance",
         main="Omnidirectional Variogram for seoul 3112")

model.3112<- fit.variogram(seoul3112.var,vgm(700,"Gau",0.5,200), fit.method = 2)
    plot(seoul3112.var,model=model.3112, col="black", pch=16,cex=1.3,
         xlab="Distance",ylab="Semivariance",
         main="Omnidirectional Variogram for seoul 3112")
```

Actually I am beginner in R and statistics. So, I am very ignorant even  about variogram. I have some query :

a)When I plot the data as a semivariogram, it looks different not as typical semivariogram! why this is happening? should I do any other thing with my data like transforming?

b)How Can I fit the model with this data? I have tried different model like "Sph","Exp" but they look like linear! why?

c)How can I understand that what initial value of sill,range,nugget I should use in `vgm()` function?

d)How can I understand that model fits with data properly?

e)For using kriging, what kind of semivariogram I should plot? only Omnidirectional semivariogram? or I should plot directional semivariogram?

f)And how can I interpret the semivariogram? I mean what actually I can understand about the data from semivariogram?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide answers to your code related questions. The rest of your questions (d, e, and f) are more theory related.

First, in your comment, when you changed the `proj4string`, the distance units should have changed on the plot. Did they? Based on your comment, it sounds like that did not happen.

a) In addition to playing around with the `cutoff` distance, also be careful of the `np` (point-pairs) that you have supporting each `bin` on the semivariogram. For example, using your updated `proj4string` information, I tried `cutoff=80` and `width=80/10` (10 bins instead of 15) to see how the semivariogram shape changed. Decreasing from 15 to 10 bins does not change where point-pairs exist, just increases the distance that each `bin` represents. Also, this approach is not necessarily what you should use, but it's an example of how to change the bins for smoother sample semivariograms (but smoother does not mean better).

[image: Comparison of 10 Bins to 15 Bins]

b) Using your code, the `"Sph"` and `"Exp"` models return `Warning: singular model in variogram fit`. This warning indicates that there is not enough data to fit some parameters of the spherical and exponential empirical models. See the [`gstat` user manual](http://www.gstat.org/) for guidance on each of the empirical equations and their parameters.

c) The `vgm()` function can be used, for example, to eye-fit sample semivariograms. If you're confused about how to plot the `vgm()` model with the sample data, try something like

```
eye_vgm = vgm(psill=1200,model="Gau",range=60,nugget=350)
plot(seoul3112.var,model=eye_vgm, col="black", pch=16,cex=1.3)
```

You're using `vgm()` in a call to `fit.variogram()`, so as long as the parameters you give to `vgm()` are reasonable (e.g. based on the sample data) and the empirical model can have parameters fitted, `fit.variogram()` will find a fit according to the `fit.method`.

Comment: Hello Jared, sorry for this comment. Could you please suggest me a forum where I can post the specific problem about variogram , kriging,gstat,spacetime etc. My work is actually with atmospheric data.Actually, recently I have posted some of my problems here but I am not getting the attention of others I don't know why probably my question are not appropriate...

Comment: I'm not the best person to ask, but depending on the question `http://gis.stackexchange.com/` or Cross Validated (`http://stats.stackexchange.com/`) may have more followers than here.

Answer (score 2):

your coordinates are degrees latitude and longitude, but you don't inform gstat that they are. Hence, gstat will assume it can compute Euclidian distances from these numbers, which do not make sense.

The advice is to learn how to use gstat after transforming your point to `SpatialPointsDataFrame` using package `sp`, and then learn how to project your data such that Euclidian distance make sense.

Comment: wow! feeling happy that author of gstat is replying my question. By the way, I wrote `proj4string(co) =  "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"` this code then rerun the variogram fitting but it's shape is same like before! Could you please give me some reference by which I can learn all the process step by step. I have got many things in internet but I don't understand exactly how should I learn. Sorry for my stupid expression.

Comment: maybe constrain the distance over which you compute the variogram (reduce `cutoff`), and focus on modelling the initial increase of semivariance; this is the most important anyway.

Comment: I have another query that is, suppose ,for projecting data I used the following code:
`coordinates(seoul3112) <- ~LON+LAT
proj4string(seoul3112) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
seoul3112_utm <- spTransform(seoul3112, 
                             CRS("+proj=utm +north +zone=52 +datum=WGS84")) `
Now  here `seoul3112_utm` is spatial points data frame with 5 slots. so if I want to plot semivariogram by gstat package then can I use this `seoul3112_utm` directly or should I transform this `seoul3112_utm` to a data.frame?

Comment: either way, recommended is to use it directly.